# How to render multiple different items in an efficient way with OpenGL

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

I am making a simple [STG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoot_%27em_up) engine with OpenGL (To be exact, with LWJGL3).In this game, there can be several different types of items(called bullet) in one frame, and each type can have 10-20 instances.I hope to find an efficient way to render it.

I have read some books about modern OpenGL and find a method called "Instanced Rendering", but it seems only to work with same instances.Should I use for-loop to draw all items directly for my case?

Another question is about memory.Should I create an VBO for each frame, since the number of items is always changing?

Answer (score 1):

Not the easiest question to answer but I'll try my best anyways.

An important property of OpenGL is that the **OpenGL context is always bound to a single thread**. So every OpenGL-method has to be called within that thread. A common way of dealing with this is using Queuing.

**Example:**
 
We are using Model-View-Controller architecture.
We have 3 threads; One to read input, one to handle received messages and one to render the scene.
Here OpenGL context is bound to rendering thread.
The first thread receives a message "Add model to position x". First thread has no time to handle the message, because there might be another message coming right after and we don't want to delay it. So we just give this message for the second thread to handle by adding it to second thread's queue.
Second thread reads the message and performs the required tasks as far as it can before OpenGL context is required. Like reads the Wavefront (.obj)-file from the memory and creates arrays from the received data.
Our second thread then queues this data to our OpenGL thread to handle. OpenGL thread generates VBOs and VAO and stores the data in there.

**Back to your question** 
**OpenGL generated Objects stay in the context memory until they are manually deleted** or the context is destroyed. So it works kind of like C, where you have to manually allocate memory and free it after it's no more used. So **you should not create new Objects for each frame, but reuse the data that stays unchanged**. Also when you have multiple objects that use the same model or texture, you should just load that model once and **apply all object specific differences on shaders**.

**Example:**
You have an environment with 10 rocks that all share the same rock model.
You load the data, store it in VBOs and attach those VBOs into a VAO. So now you have a VAO defining a rock.
You generate 10 rock entities that all have position, rotation and scale. When rendering, you first bind the shader, then bind the model and texture, then loop through the stone entities and for each stone entity you bind that entity's position, rotation and scale (usually stored in a transformationMatrix) and render.

```
bind shader
load values to shader's uniform variables that don't change between entities.
bind model and texture (as those stay the same for each rock)
for(each rock in rocks){
   load values to shader's uniform variables that do change between each rock, like the transformation.
   render
}
unbind shader
```

Note: You don't need to unbind/bind shader each frame if you only use one shader. Same goes for VAO's and every other OpenGL object as well. So the binding will also stay over each rendering cycle.

Hope this will help you when getting started. Altho I would recommend some tutorial that might have a bit more context to it.

Answer (score 0):

> I have read some books about modern OpenGL and find a method called
> "Instanced Rendering", but it seems only to work with same
> instances.Should I use for-loop to draw all items directly for my
> case?
>
> Another question is about memory.Should I create an VBO for each
> frame, since the number of items is always changing?

These both depend on the amount of bullets you plan on having. If you think you will have less than a thousand bullets, you can almost certainly push all of them to a VBO each frame and upload and your end users will not notice. If you plan on some obscene amount, then don't do this.

I would say that you should write everything each frame because it's the simplest to do *right now*, and if you start noticing performance issues then you need to look into instancing or some other method. When you get to "later" you should be more comfortable with OpenGL and find out ways to optimize it that won't be over your head (not saying it is over your head right now, but more experience can only help make it less complex later on).

Culling bullets not on the screen either should be on your radar.

If you plan on having a ridiculous amount of bullets on screen, then you should say so and we can talk about more advanced methods, however my guess is that if you ever reach that limit on today's hardware then you have a large ambitious game with a zoomed out camera and a significant amount of entities on screen, or you are zoomed up and likely have a mess on your screen anyways.

Answer (score 0):

20 objects is *nothing*. Your program will be plenty fast no matter how you draw them.

When you have 10000 objects, then you'll want to ask for an efficient way.

Until then, draw them whichever way is most convenient. This probably means a separate draw call per object.